# load content and background image at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I'm loading in an external HTML with Ajax but this external html has a large background image, how can I display a loader until the background image has loaded too?

Code:

```
$( ".content" ).load("game.html", function() {
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded, a javascript code for detecting when images are loaded

your code would then be something like:

```
$( ".content" ).load("game.html", function() {
   $('.content').imagesLoaded(function () {
     remove loader
   });
});
```